# Alignment of "link" and "label" using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using "href" and a "label" but alignment is not proper. They are in same line but "My Text" is little above "myImage".

```
<div class="col-md-6 bottom">
   <a href="~mydata"><img src="~/Images/myImage.png"/></a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 bottom">
   Html.Label("", "My Text")
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the class `.form-control-static`. More information here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static